# Page loads once with no errors, multiple 403's after reload

Tags: theme, magento2.4.3, static-content, http-status-403

I've been working with Magento for a number of years but I've never come across this before. I'm working on a custom theme for a new site - vanilla Magento 2.4.3 Open Source install - and recently after adding some custom CSS and changing the minicart icon, I keep getting 403 errors from resources in the /pub/static directory. I've set the correct permissions, clean cache, flush cache and the page (any page) will load fine once. If I navigate to another page, cart, anything, the next page that loads returns 403's all from the /pub/static directory.

I know it's not my theme - the admin area is behaving the same way. I managed to set the theme back to Luma and the problem persists.

My dev server is a bare metal machine running Ubuntu 20.04 with Apache, MariaDB, Elasticsearch and Redis.

I've only found [this][New Magento 2.4.1 installation with assets only appearing on first page load, when not created yet in static folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/341192/new-magento-2-4-1-installation-with-assets-only-appearing-on-first-page-load-wh) other thread with an issue similar but it's not quite the same.

Comment: The 403 must be generating an error log somewhere - check all your logs to try and narrow it down...

Answer (score 0):

**Try below command once and check site**

```
php bin/magento  maintenance:enable

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento  maintenance:disable
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked my Apache logs and saw several entries like this:

```
[Tue Feb 01 03:30:10.546946 2022] [core:error] [pid 361308] [client 199.18.157.82:21614] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible:
```

Which reminded me that a recent change requires the document root to be the /pub directory. So, I looked at my vhost configuration and saw my document root was set to /pub and also my  configuration was set to /pub as well. As soon as I changed the  configuration to apple the options one folder higher, the errors went away. I honestly don't know if this is the right way to fix this problem but it solved the issue for me.